# WPF анимации нескольких элементов

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, xaml

Есть анимированная Grid панель которая расширяется при наводке курсора на неё. Добавил на этот Grid изображение, хочу чтобы при наводке на Grid ещё и переворачивалось изображение по вертикали с анимацией.

```
    <Grid Width="40" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="#FF1B1C23" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <Image x:Name="TestImage" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="19" Margin="11,5,0,0" Source="Source/Three_Pase.png"/>
        <Grid.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                        <EventTrigger.Actions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TestImage" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle"
                                                    By="180" Duration="0:0:1"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" To="150"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger.Actions>
                    </EventTrigger>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                        <EventTrigger.Actions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" To="40"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger.Actions>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Style>
    </Grid>
```

Помогите разобраться, где допустил ошибку.

Comment: А сейчас что не так?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ System.InvalidOperationException: "Дерево Storyboard в стиля Style не указывать TargetName. Удалите TargetName "TestImage"."

Comment: А у вас есть объект с названием `TestImage` внутри стиля `Grid`?)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Да, выше код

Comment: Ну, я вижу у вас сначала картинку, потом я вижу объявление стиля, в котором анимации. Вы уверены, что "ДА", картинка есть в стиле `Grid`?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Не совсем если честно понимаю. У меня есть Grid, на который я положил картинку, ниже обработка самого Grida при наведении на него - он увеличивается. Картинка остаётся на месте. Вопрос в том, что я не могу понять того, как в эту обработку добавить переворот ещё и картинки.

Comment: Представьте, что есть некие уровни, в которых вы размещаете объекты. Есть уровень стилей, а есть уровень, хм, представления что ли. Так вот, эти два уровня являются индивидуальными и самостоятельными, то есть, вы пишете `<Grid.Style>` (переопределяете стиль элемента), далее в нем вы просите найти объект с именем `TestImage`, которого естественно нету на уровне стилей, он есть выше, на уровне представления. Поэтому вам и говорят, что "нету такого элемента на уровне стилей, уберите поиск по имени". Вам надо вынести все триггеры за пределы стиля, либо изображение засунуть в стиль.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Кажется я понял. Спасибо. Сейчас попробую.

Comment: То есть вот, [вынесли](https://pastebin.com/jtscPh2q) все за пределы стиля и вот уже ваша картинка будет искаться, НО, этого недостаточно, ибо вы неверно указали то, что хотите анимировать. `RenderTransform.Angle` - попробуйте задайте этот `Angle` просто картинке без анимации, что увидите? Увидите там `RenderTransform` со свойством `Angle`? Нет, вы увидите там нечто такое: `<Image.RenderTransform><RotateTransform Angle="0"/></Image.RenderTransform>`. То есть, в анимации вы должны указать `(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)`.

Comment: НО и этого тоже недостаточно для анимации, ибо по умолчанию не установлен `Angle` у объекта и чтобы было что анимировать, вам надо задать значение `Angle` по умолчанию (как, я уже описал выше). И вот тогда у вас все будет работать.